# Storing a cookie based on path and query string

Tags: javascript, cookies, query-string

I want to store a different cookie for every page on a website. The cookie will record if the user has taken a particular action on that page.

This is fine is the page has a straight-forward URL. I can store the cookie like this:

```
// https://www.example.com/path/to/page.html
document.cookie = "name=" + value + ";max-age=2419200;path=" + location.pathname;
```

But if the page has a URL that uses a query string to present different "pages", this falls over. I've tried the following with no luck (i.e. the cookie isn't even stored in Chrome):

```
// https://www.example.com/path/to/page.html?story=10
document.cookie = "name=" + value + ";max-age=2419200;path=" + location.pathname + location.search;
```

[The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) only have arguments for `path` and `domain`. Is it possible to store a cookie based on query string too? Perhaps not. So is there a well-used work-around?

Comment: append the query string to your value, that will give you url with query specific cookies.

Comment: @n01ze - That won't give me a different value per "page" (including query string). It will just overwrite the value for that path (excluding query string).

Comment: This is not nice to the client user if there are a LOT of cookies.